# If the selected index is greater than the maximum index, the program continues to count the indexes in a roll form (python)

Tags: python, string, list, indexing, count

For example: List `["cat", "dog", "wolf", "mouse", "fish"]` has 5 words.
The user selected the index 8
The program will count in a circular fashion and reach index 2 or the word "wolf" again.

Comment: What have you tried? This isn't a free coding service I'm afraid. How would you obtain "dog" from index 2 noting that python uses 0-based indexing? How would you obtain index 2 after the user has selected index 8? Please add more detail because at first it seems you could use the "mod" `%` operator, however your example is confusing and perhaps incorrect.

Comment: Yes, my mistake. I meant wolf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use mod (%) operator.

The code below could help solve your problem

```
list = ["cat", "dog", "wolf", "mouse", "fish"]
list_len = len(list) # calculate list length
index = int(input("input an index"))
print(list[(index % list_len) - 1]) # In python, arrays start at 0. So we subtract 1
```